# custom VCL script for Fastly to prevent bots attack

Tags: magento2, security, fastly

Currently, our Magento is using Fastly. Last month, we got attacked by bots. They are trying to place the order as a guest thru an API call. Is there any VCL script that I can write in Fastly, so I can block the bot's attack?

I did Google and find the following rate limit counter.

https://developer.fastly.com/reference/vcl/functions/rate-limiting/ratelimit-ratecounter-increment/

But I don't know why it doesn't work when I upload the VCL script.

anyone can advise me what is the correct script? so that if the bot attack, the server will throw an error code like 444

thanks!